Aggregate Balance For Account Between Rows Based On Date and ID
I'm trying to write a query that will aggregate the balance of open user accounts, but I'm having trouble getting them to add up in the desired order. The code should sum up the balance for every different row under an account in the order of oldest to newest and, if there are more than one row for a particular date, in order of ID from highest to lowest. The issue is mainly a problem on accounts with multiple openings on the same day because the entire balance for the day gets lumped together, instead of being calculated individually.
Here's an example of what I want.



AccountNumber
ID
OpenDate
Balance
AvailableCredit
TotalBalance
Aggregate




100
1
9/7/2024
$1,000
$1,500
$2,500
$2,500


100
2
9/8/2024
$2,000
$2,500
$4,500
$7,000


100
90
9/10/2024
$3,000
$3,500
$6,500
$13,500


100
3
9/10/2024
$1,000
$1,500
$2,500
$16,000


100
97
9/11/2024
$2,000
$2,500
$4,500
$20,500



Right now, I am pulling the data by joining a second copy of the table and running a SUM of Balance and AvailableCredit where the AccountNumber is the same and the OpenDate is <= the first table. This means that anything on the same day gets SUMmed together, like this:



AccountNumber
ID
OpenDate
Balance
AvailableCredit
TotalBalance
Aggregate




100
1
9/7/2024
$1,000
$1,500
$2,500
$2,500


100
2
9/8/2024
$2,000
$2,500
$4,500
$7,000


100
90
9/10/2024
$3,000
$3,500
$6,500
$16,000


100
3
9/10/2024
$1,000
$1,500
$2,500
$16,000


100
97
9/11/2024
$2,000
$2,500
$4,500
$20,500



This all seems clunky to begin with, and I can't seem to get the code to do what I want. Any help would be appreciated, thank you. A version of my current code is included below.
SELECT AccountNumber, 
       ID, 
       OpenDate, 
       Balance, 
       AvailableCredit, 
       (Balance + AvailableCredit) AS TotalBalance,
       (SELECT SUM(Balance) + SUM(AvailableCredit)
        FROM Table AS T2
        WHERE T2.AccountNumber = AccountNumber
          AND T2.OpenDate <= OpenDate) AS Aggregate
FROM Table

I have tried using GROUP BY clauses and PARTITION/OVER clauses to get the data to aggregate properly, but they never behave the way I expect them to. I also tried adding a T2.ID >= ID clause to the joined table, but that didn't work how I thought it would either.
Thanks again!

You need to show sample raw data in addition to your desired results

I added your data and code to a fiddle to help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/z8Ljs9me

Isn't this a simple window aggregate? SUM(Balance + AvailableCredit) OVER(PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY OpenDate, ID DESC)

The suggestion by Siggermannen appears to work https://dbfiddle.uk/Bbft6GaS

Why do you want the ID = 90 row to be handled before the ID = 3 row? Same date.

What version of SQL Server? Later versions have more advanced windowing functions...

You can use the window function version of SUM:
SELECT *
  , SUM(TotalBalance) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY OpenDate, ID DESC) as Aggregate
FROM [data]
ORDER BY AccountNumber, OpenDate, ID DESC

See it work here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/3gKXWN29


TotalBalance would appear to be Balance + AvailableCredit -- so sum on that, and you should be good.

Works as asked for. But the question is (still) why ID desc is should be used?

It was bugging me, and I finally found some obscure code I wrote quite some time ago that does the same thing in (imho) a pointlessly highbrow fashion.  Just tossing it here, might need some minor debugging.  sum(Balance + AvailableCredit) over(order by OpenDate, ID desc rows unbounded preceding) 

@PhilipKelley that's a small performance optimization because SUM defaults to RANGE instead of ROWS which is a bit slower
